# Automatic numbering of Javascript's switch() cases?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to automatically number the cases of a switch() statement? I need each case to increment by 1's.

So something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rWWhJ/

```
switch(x)
```

Say I want to add another day after Tuesday. I'd have to add one to every number next to it manually. Is there a way to do this automatically? I tried Notepad++'s collumn selection, but that messes up the other lines. All I need to be able to do is increment each case number by 1, starting from the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var day = days[x];
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rWWhJ/1/)